# cart remove is not update total item and total area

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, cart

I did cart remove with json get method. Its product delete but, total item and total area is not updating. help me...

```
$("#mycart").on('click', 'a.remove-item', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var pcode = $(this).attr("data-code");
    $(this).parent().fadeOut();
    $.getJSON("sepet.php", {"remove_code":pcode},
        function(data){
            $("#total_items").html(data.items);
            $("#total_items").trigger();
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Is getJSON callback function running? Put a console.log in there and let us know :)

Comment: yes its working. only total price is not updating. how can I do?

Comment: Does data.items has the correct value?, post your JSON, and the HTML where #total_items is.

Comment: $total_item is cart count. When I delete the cart product is not update to count and total price. Only product delete. When I delete product, I want to update total ıtems and total price.

Comment: Total items : <input type="button" id="total_items" value="">

Total price : .cd-cart-total